# Six square roots of a $2$ by $2$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Yesterday I posted a question about finding the four roots of a 2 by 2 matrix. I worked it out based on the method of Diagonalization. Since the algebra is quite cumbersome (finding eigenvalues, eigenvectors etc), Achilles Hui proposed a different method, using the principal idea of Cayley Hamilton. After several self made exercises, for sure I found the 4 roots of each 2 by 2 matrix. Then I wondered it this method also works for complex entries and so I made up one randomly: $ \begin{bmatrix}i & 1\\2 & -i\end{bmatrix}$ and I squared it.....which gave me the unit matrix $ \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$. But wait a minute, I already know the 4 roots of the unit matrix: $ \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$,$ \begin{bmatrix}-1 & 0\\0 & -1\end{bmatrix}$,$ \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ and $ \begin{bmatrix}0 & -1\\-1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$. That's four already. But now also $ \begin{bmatrix}i & 1\\2 & -i\end{bmatrix}$ as well as $ \begin{bmatrix}-i & -1\\-2 & i\end{bmatrix}$ happen to be roots of $ \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$. That's 6 square roots, and I can't find them with the Cayley Hamilton method (I got only $2$ with that method). So my question is, when complex entries are allowed in a 2 by 2 matrix as an answer, how many square roots can a 2 by 2 matrix (with real entries as you can see in my example) have? I got $6$, so maybe $8$ perhaps? Does anybody know, and is there some theorem (obviously not the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra) that applies to my question?

Comment: Because it has duplicate eigenvalues, the $2×2$ identity matrix  ${\displaystyle  {\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}} } $  has infinitely many symmetric rational [square roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_2_by_2_matrix)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner. Interesting link. apparently having infinitely many square roots is not only reserved for the unit matrix, but for any square matrix that has a double eigenvalue?

Comment: @imranfat Any matrix with an eigenvalue of *geometric* multiplicity $2$ or higher.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Ok, silly question perhaps, but what is the difference between an analytic and geometric multiplicity?

Comment: @imranfat the terminology you're looking for is algebraic and geometric multiplicity. Algebraic multiplicity refers to the multiplicity of the root in the characteristic polynomial, while the geometric multiplicity refers to the dimension of the associated eigenspace

Comment: @NoahSolomon. Thanks, makes sense

Comment: @BenGrossmann,  So the matrix $ \begin{bmatrix}1 & -1\\1 & 3\end{bmatrix}$ has a double root $\lambda=2$, so this matrix is supposed to infinitely many square roots? I did find 4 with the Cayley Hamilton approach.

Comment: That has *algebraic* multiplicity $2$, but not *geometric*

Comment: @J.W.Tanner In that case I am still confused what's the difference?

Comment: the dimension of the eigenspace is only $1$

Comment: @imranfat Everything J.W. Tanner said is right. For a $2 \times 2$ matrix, we can only have infinitely many square roots if we have a multiple of the identity matrix

Comment: Thanks all, much clearer !!!